# What is the default install location for java on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, java

Where does javaw.exe live on a standard Vista installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe;

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre[version number]\bin
```

Comment: close.  Instead of jdk it's jre[version]

Answer (score 1):

The Java Runtime Environment file `javaw.exe` (which is the non-windowed version of `java.exe`) is located at:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre[version]\bin\javaw.exe

In my case, I've got 5 folders in my Java folder, each a different version:

> jre1.6.0
>
> jre1.6.0_03
>
> jre1.6.0_05
>
> jre1.6.0_07
>
> jre6

Answer (score 0):

It's in usually `c:\user\your-username\AppData\LocalLow\Java\`

Search for the current version and copy/paste it to your desired location.

Comment: This both contradicts the other answers and does not work on my system... I also recommend you do *not* copy Java binaries (such as `javaw.exe`) into random folders.